# Cannot connect to database server (mysql)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I was working on mysql everything worked fine at first until I installed mariadb on my pc.

after that when i use mysql workbench to connect to my database, i get the following error:

[image: error]

I think it is a conflict error that occurred between mysql and mariadb but I don't know how to resolve it.

I tried to find out what the mariadb service is to stop it and see if it solves the problem but I couldn't find it.

what to do please ?

Comment: hello , the version is : 8.0.19 and no i don't have a xampp

Comment: Both MySQL and mariaDB by default use port 3306. If you have mariaDB running and you have not added the user account to it that would explain this

Comment: Are you on Windows or a Linux

Comment: i'm on Windows bro

Comment: PS: MySQL WorkBench is not guaranteed to work with mariaDB

Comment: how can i stop mariadb or change its port so that it can work with mysql?

Comment: Keyin `service` in the windows search box, on the Task bar, click on `Service App`, look for a service name of `MYSQL` or  `MariaDB`

Comment: I have already done that but I can't find the one for mariadb I don't know its name, I type mariadb but I don't have any result by cons that of mysql it is well in "service" that I knew it but the one from mariadb i can't find it

Comment: Simple solution would be to uninstall mariaDB

Comment: I have already done this but it does not work I think even if I deleted it I do not know really deleted because the error still persists.

when I downloaded it I received it in a .zip file, I took this .zip and I unzipped it in my documents.

now I deleted the .zip file and I also deleted the file that I unzipped from mariadb but the error is still there suddenly I checked if it is in the C directory but from what I see he doesn't exist there

Comment: still no one to help me please ??